# Many to Many using foreign_keys option

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I need to create a many to many relationship between two tables. I need to specify the `foreign_keys` option because I have other references in both tables to each other.

Tried multiple approaches using `Class` declaration of the assiciation table and `Table` object directly.

When I remove the `foreign_keys` option on both `User and`Feature` class, it works but when I add other fields with mappings between these two classes, I get the Multiple paths exception.

```py
feature_user = Table(
    'feature_user',
    Base.metadata,
    Column('feature_id', Integer, ForeignKey('features.id')),
    Column('user_id', Integer, ForeignKey('users.id')),
)

class Feature(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'features'

    id = getIdColumn()

    # other fields...

    cpm_engineers = relationship(
        'User',
        secondary=feature_user,
        foreign_keys=[feature_user.columns.user_id],
        back_populates='cpm_engineer_of',
    )

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = getIdColumn()

    # other fields...

    cpm_engineer_of = relationship(
        'Feature',
        secondary=feature_user,
        foreign_keys=[feature_user.columns.feature_id],
        back_populates='cpm_engineers',
    )
```

When creating a new `User` of a `Feature`, I get the following error:
`sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Feature.cpm_engineers - there are no foreign keys linking these tables via secondary table 'feature_user'.  Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify 'primaryjoin' and 'secondaryjoin' expressions.`

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue was I was trying to use the same table to store many-to-many associations for multiple bindings, e.g. feature-tester-user, feature-developer-user, etc. This is, of course, wrong. I needed to add a custom JOIN using a third column (e.g. add a new `role` column) or create a separate table for each association (which is what i did in the end).